# Showing weak convergence for $sin^2(nx)$ and determining its limit distribution

Tags: analysis, distribution-theory, weak-convergence

I am currently struggling a bit with showing weak convergence for $\sin^2(nx)$ and its limit distribution.

My solution so far, with $\phi \in D(\mathbb{R})$;

$$\left<\sin^2(nx),\phi(x)\right> = \int_{\mathbb R} \sin^2(nx) \phi(x) dx$$

$$=\int_{\mathbb R} \frac{1}{2}(1-\cos(2nx)) \phi(x)$$

I'm stuck at this point.

Possible ideas to solve it:

$\bullet$ Partial integration to get out a $\frac{1}{2n}$ and let $n \to \infty$ and see what happens

$\bullet$ Use triangle inequality and approximate $\cos(2nx)$ to get rid of trigonometric terms.

Would someone like to give a hint what's next in this solution?

Comment: Check out the [Riemann-Lebesgue lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann–Lebesgue_lemma)

Comment: Rieman-Lebesgue lemma, have a try?

Comment: Thats a new lemma to me. Would you mind show the solution with this lemma?

Comment: The Fourier transforms yields $\delta(k)- \delta(k-2n)-\delta(k+2n)$ as Fourier inetgrals for $e$

Comment: Im not familiar with that way of solving it, according to the course literature I am supposed so solve it in either of the two mentioned ways. Does someone know how?

Comment: The Fourier transforms yields $\delta(k)- \delta(k-2n)-\delta(k+2n)$ as Fourier integrals for $e^{i x k -s x ^2}$ in the limit $s\to \infty$. $n\to \infty$ leaves a $\delta$ with inverse $1(x)$ .

Comment: What is $D(\mathbb{R})$ here?

Comment: Denotes testfunctions